# tornado Websockets updates on different pages

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am new to the tornado framework in python and is currently encountering difficulties in Websockets. I am trying to make a chat website with different pages [lobby and chatroom]. The lobby shows all available rooms and should be updated live.

Currently, I have one Websocket Handler that handles the chat messages. Is it possible for one handler to manage both lobby update and chat messages at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but I think would be better make separate socket for lobby and chat-room. For storing shared data you can use inctance of Aplication or heandler's class
Also you can see official example.

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py